# Should JSF 2.0 Managed Beans be made Serializable if they are always Request Scoped?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

All of my JSF 2.0 Managed Beans are Request Scoped. Do I need to bother to make them Serializable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not necessary on RequestScoped beans. On the contrary, if your beans are SessionScoped you need to make them Serializable.

Answer (score 0):

No, but for the 0.001% chance the system will give them the same id it's best to make them Serializable.

Answer (score 0):

If your bean is in request scope there's no need to serialize your bean..

However if your bean is viewScoped there is every need to serialize your bean...